# how can i configure hangfire dashboard in console application?

Tags: asp.net-core, console-application, hangfire

i am using hangfire nuget package to schedule the jobs in asp.net core console application

i tried all the ways to configure the dashboard to the console application

how can i host the webpage from console application???

i have created startup.cs class for dashboard configuration

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

    namespace PulsarHangFire
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IApplicationBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
                app.UseHangfireServer();
            }
        }
    }
```

can anyone tell me how can i move forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Startup.cs file (or get one from the .NET Core Web App template) and configure the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other required services ...

    services.AddHangfire(configuration =>
    {
        // Do pretty much the same as you'd do with 
        // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration in classic .NET

        // NOTE: logger and activator would be configured automatically, 
        // and in most cases you don't need to configure those.

        configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(...);

        // ... maybe something else, e.g. configuration.UseConsole()
    });
}
```

Finally add the Hangfire dashboard:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager)
{
    // ... previous pipeline stages, e.g. app.UseAuthentication()

    app.UseHangfireDashboard(...);

   // ... next pipeline stages, e.g. app.UseMvc()

   // then you may configure your recurring jobs here:
   recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(...);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1181#issuecomment-391177593)